# Getting Error with adaptive payment using Paypal MPL library in android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I m getting below message with adaptive payment using Paypal MPL library in android.

`This app contain payment capabilities that aren't compatible with your device`

is adaptive payment using this library is *deprecated* ?

Comment: have you get any solution for this problem ?

Comment: No,Not till now...but my research conclude that we have to use Express check out for Adaptive payment Or you can manage it from back-end

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)